# Return code in Python Fileobject.Close()

Tags: python

I am getting a return code 2 instead of "None" while I close a file object.

```
output = []
    cmd = cmd.lstrip()
    if cmd.startswith('"') == True and cmd.count('"') > 2:
        found = re.search(r'^".*?"', cmd)
        if found != None:
            shortName = win32api.GetShortPathName(found.group(0).replace('"',''))
            cmd = cmd.replace(found.group(0), shortName)

    rc = None
    if debugOutput == False:
        progOutput = os.popen(cmd)
        line = progOutput.readline()
        while (line) != "":
            if capture == True:
                output.append(self.chomp(line))
            if log == True:
                print self.chomp(line)
            line = progOutput.readline()
        rc = progOutput.close()
    else:
        print "Would have executed: %s" % cmd

    if rc == None:
        rc = 0
    if capture == True:
        return rc, output
    else:
        return rc
```

The return code of **"rc"** is 2 instead on none.
Do anybody have an idea what is the error code **2** in python?

Answer (score 0):

Docs for [os.popen](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.popen):

> os.popen(command[, mode[, bufsize]])
>
> ...
>
> The exit status of the command (encoded in the format specified for `wait()`) is available as the return value of the `close()` method of the file object, except that when the exit status is zero (termination without errors), `None` is returned.

So this error code comes from the OS ("file not found", according to google).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But file is present there. And this is occuring only on a particular machine. Not all the machines. 
The return code of Close() method is 2 instead of None.

Comment: I cannot really argue with that, since I do not know what ``cmd`` is in your case. But I'm inclined to believe the documentation. If it says that ``close`` returns the exitcode of ``cmd``, then your ``cmd`` returns 2 for some reason on this particular machine.